# Pesquisa em arquivos json aninhados rails

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails

tenho uns arquivos que são: serviços, órgãos, unidades.
Os órgãos possuem serviços e possuem unidades.
Eu, nos jsons que possuo, consigo retornar até a parte em que, exemplo:
localhost/api/organs/.json. Que aí ele retorna os serviços e as unidades que o órgão possui. O que desejo é que quando chegar ao ponto que expus seja possível, usando a id de um serviço ou unidade, acessar este serviço ou unidade.

```html
json.array!(@organs) do |organ|
 json.id @organ.id.to_s
 json.unit do
  json.id organ.unit.id.to_s 
  json.name organ.unit.name
  json.address organ.organ.unit.address
  json.coordinates organ.organ.unit.coordinates
  json.schedules organ.unit.schedules
  json.phone organ.unit.phone
  json.email organ.unit.email
 end if organ.unit
 json.service @organ.service
```

Comment: Resolveu sua duvida?